# Adobe Acrobat 9 Javascript to add footer to document

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

I have been searching all over for a way to do this. Most suggestions say to use `addField()` and add a form field to the PDF and set a footer that way. However, I do see that Acrobat has the ability to manually add a footer. (Document > Header & Footer > Add). Is there someway that I can do the equivalent in acrobat Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached a script with the add field method. More you will find in this discussion: https://forums.adobe.com/message/1166404#1166404
Enjoy, Reinhard

```
function setPageNoAsFooter {
    var Box2Width = 50
    for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {
        var aRect = this.getPageBox("Crop",p);
        var TotWidth = aRect[2] - aRect[0]
        var bStart=(TotWidth/2)-(Box2Width/2)
        var bEnd=((TotWidth/2)+(Box2Width/2))
        var fp = this.addField(String("xftPage"+p+1), "text", p, [bStart,30,bEnd,15]);
        fp.value = "Page: " + String(p+1)+ "/" + this.numPages;
        fp.textSize = 6;
        fp.readonly = true;
        fp.alignment="center";
    }
}

function RemoveFooter() {
    for (var p = 0; p < this.numPages; p++) {
        var x = this.removeField(String("xftPage"+p+1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes - You just need to add it as a watermark.

The following adds a multiline watermark to each page of the current document 1 inch down and 1 inch over from the upper-right corner.

```
this.addWatermarkFromText({
  cText: "Confidential Document\rA. C. Robat",
  nTextAlign: app.constants.align.right,
  nHorizAlign: app.constants.align.right,
  nVertAlign: app.constants.align.top,
  nHorizValue: -72, nVertValue: -72
});
```

See the Acrobat DC documentation here for a full description of the parameters. The cocumentation is for Acrobat DC but this particular method hasn't changed since earlier versions and will work in 9.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/Acro12_MasterBook/JS_API_AcroJS/Doc_methods.htm?rhtocid=_6_1_8_23_1_9#TOC_addWatermarkFromTextbc-10